# Is there a way for me to use a List<string> property class with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

This is the class:

```
namespace backend
{
    [Table("Products")]
    public class Product
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? Category { get; set; }

        public string? Short { get; set; }

        public string? Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public float Price { get; set; }

        public string? MainImage { get; set; }

        public float  Disccount { get; set; }
        
        public string[]? Images { get; set; } // List<string>

    }
}
```

I've tried to run EF migrations but it appears that [] is not supported and, if I make it a List, it will ask for this List's key but it's just an array of strings

What am I doing wrong? Is not possible to add arrays as classes properties in EF?

Comment: Depends, which version of EF?

Comment: How do you expect the array to be mapped onto tables / columns? You could use a value converter to save it as a json string. Or you could define a new dependent class to map the values to another table.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the use case. Does the data be used in a relational child table way (1:many)? Or is it really just a list of some urls that don't have any further relations within the database?

For the first case, take a look at [Caius answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72082865/1838048). The second approach would be to write a type converter and register it within EF core. In that case your underlying type in the database would be some kind of string (e.g. nvarchar(max)) and EF core makes the conversion on the client side

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Product>()
        .Property(e => e.Images)
        .HasConversion(
            v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v),
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(v));
}
```

Instead of JSON you could also use some other approach like `string.Join()` and `string.Split()`, that's up to you. Further information can be found at [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-value-converter).

Comment: Don't forget to also add a value comparer, so entity framework can track changes:
.... `new ValueComparer<List<string>>((c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2), c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())), c => c.ToList()));`

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with doing what a relational database would expect:

```
namespace backend
{
    [Table("Products")]
    public class Product
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? Category { get; set; }

        public string? Short { get; set; }

        public string? Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public float Price { get; set; }

        public string? MainImage { get; set; }

        public float  Disccount { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<ProductImage>? Images { get; set; } //make it a new hashset in the constructor, btw

    }

    [Table("ProductImages")]
    public class ProductImage
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? Url { get; set; }

        public long ProductId { get; set; }
        
        public Product? Product { get; set; }

}
```

this way you can add more data to the image, like "front view", "side view", "version 2" etc, and EF can map it like it knows how to; as a separate table that is 1:M related

> Is not possible to add arrays as classes properties in EF?

Technically, the `ICollection<ProductImage>` is a property that is an "array"..  but out-of-the-box, not arrays of primitives, no

Comment: There are other ways, btw, such as storing json or csv but I feel a moral obligation to avoid outlining them! Json isn't so bad because at least it's probably properly supported DB side, but CSV style is just nasty; do please avoid it

Answer (score 1):

*string* is primitive type. you can't save list of primitive types in entity framework instead you can save your data in one property which is a single string then define another property to just get and set the main string property.

```
 public class example {
    public string AttachmentsString { get ; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<string> Attachments { 
        get => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(AttachmentsString) ? AttachmentsString.Split(",").ToList() : new List<string>(); 
        set => AttachmentsString = string.Join(",", value); 
    }
}
```

then in your controllers or service just manipulate with *Attachments* property.