# How can I use a code and value string pair in an EF model in place of an Enum

Tags: c#, enums

When defining a model class in C#, I can use an Enum, which by default saves the integer value to the database. I would like to define an Enum-like class, which has a short string or constant value to be saved to the database and different value to be displayed when referring it in code.

For example: an Enum of credit card providers would be...

```
public enum CreditCardProvider
{
    Visa = 1,
    [Display(Name ="Master Card")]
    MasterCard = 2,
    [Display(Name ="American Express")]
    AmericanExpress = 3
}
```

I would like to use an object which basically works very similarly, but returns a const / string value instead of an integer, such as:

```
public class CreditCardProvider
{
    Visa = "VI",
    [Display(Name ="Master Card")]
    MasterCard = "MC",
    [Display(Name ="American Express")]
    AmericanExpress = "AX"
}
```

Is this possible? In my C# model, instead of the CreditCardProvider enum Type saving the integer value, the CreditCardProvider class would persist the codes (VI, MC, AX).

UPDATE:

Based on the link below, I have worked out how to achieve my goal (albeit it's a bit more involved that using Enums).

My struct class includes a constructor, Get and List methods:

```
public struct CreditCardItem {

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CreditCardItem(string code, string name)
    {
        Code = code;
        Name = name;
    }

    public static CreditCardItem Get(string code)
    {
        return List().Where(_ => _.Code == code).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static List<CreditCardItem> List()
    {
        var creditCardItemList = new List<CreditCardItem>() {
        new CreditCardItem("VI", "Visa"),
        new CreditCardItem("MC", "MasterCard"),
        new CreditCardItem("DI", "Diners Card"),
        new CreditCardItem("AX", "American Express")
    };

        return creditCardItemList;
    }
}
```

In the ApplicationDbContext I map the Code field of the struct to and from the string value to persist the code in the DB.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PlaygroundModel>()
.Property(ccc => ccc.CreditCardCode)
.HasConversion(ccc => ccc.Code, ccc => CreditCardItem.Get(ccc))
.HasMaxLength(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own converter for properties of an EF model. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72082977/1838048